# Jest.fn() not working in React unit-test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs

I'm testing a component method called `handleSubmit` (the name doesn't matter...).

#### Test

```
// ...imported all modules at the top, including enzyme

it('should submit form data', () => {
  let form = shallow(<Form />);
  let handleSubmit = jest.fn(); // <= this doesn't work!!

  form.find('.submit-btn').simulate('click');

  expect(form.find('.submit-btn').length).toEqual(1);
  expect(handleSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

#### Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class CarnetSidebarForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      title: ''
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    const target = e.target;
    const value = target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let payload = {
      title: this.state.title
    };

    this.postCard(payload);

    console.log('Payload: ', payload);
  }

  postCard(data) {
    return axios.post('http://localhost:4000/api/cards', data)
      .then(response => {
        console.log('Response: ', response.message);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="card-form-panel">
        <form className="card-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="card-title-field">Title</label>
            <input className="form-control"
               type="text"
               placeholder="Title..."
               id="card-title-field"
               name="title"
               value={this.state.title}
               onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </div>

          <input className="card-submit-btn btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CarnetSidebarForm;
```

I keep getting this error message, which is annoying now:

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

Expected mock function to have been called.
```

But if I create a fake component inside the test then it works

```
it('should submit form data', () => {
  let handleSubmit = jest.fn();

  // create a fake component
  let form = mount(
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input className="submit-btn" type="submit" value="Save" />
    </form>
  );

  form.find('.submit-btn').simulate('submit');

  expect(form.find('.submit-btn').length).toEqual(1);
  expect(handleSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Is it something to do with `shallow()` or `mount` from `enzyme` with imported components? I've spent many days looking for answers but I'm lost.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to pass `handleSubmit` as a prop? you are setting `handleSubmit ` but not using it within your component!

Comment: @Shaoz Can you post the minimal code of your component? Are you passing the `handleSubmit` as `prop` or it is a component method?

Comment: @HardikModha, thanks for responding. `handleSubmit` is a component method. I have updated my question with the component code.

Comment: Thanks for the update. You'll need to mock the component method as suggested by @rauliyohmc. Have you given it a try?

Comment: @HardikModha, yes try his suggestion but I'm still getting the same error `Expected mock function to have been called.` So something isn't right with `shallow` or `mount` and `jest.fn()`, I think.

Comment: @Shaoz Did it work for you?

Comment: @HardikModha none of the answers work at the moment.

Comment: @Shaoz I've updated my answer with an example. Can you take a look?

Answer (score 4):

Adding to @rauliyohmc answer. The problem is that even after mocking the component method it is not getting called and instead, the actual method is called. So, after spending some time on it, I found out a solution. You'll need to `forceUpdate` your component after mocking its method.

```
it('should submit form data', () => {
  let form = mount(<Form />); // need to use mount to make it work.
  form.instance().handleSubmit = jest.fn();
  form.update(); // equivalent to calling form.instance().forceUpdate();

  form.find('.submit-btn').simulate('submit'); // simulated event must be submit

  expect(form.find('.submit-btn').length).toEqual(1);
  expect(form.instance().handleSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Minimal example: [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6d874637b32a2e1c9b62dd07182188f1)

Comment: It's not working at all. Now I'm getting this error `Method “props” is only meant to be run on a single node. 0 found instead.`.

Comment: Seems like the error is from another test case, because in this test case you are not accessing props at all. Can you comment out all other test cases and see?

Comment: I commented out everything except for your solution, but it still gives me the error `Method “props” is only meant to be run on a single node. 0 found instead.` So it must be from this test case. As you said we're not accessing any props, so why is it mentioning it?

Comment: ok I modified the selector to `form.find('.submit-btn').first()` and the error `Method “props” is only meant to be run on a single node. 0 found instead.` is all gone,. But now my old favourite error `Expected mock function to have been called.` is back again :(

Comment: You'll need to mount the component. Somehow shallow rendering is not working. I've also updated my answer. I've also created a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6d874637b32a2e1c9b62dd07182188f1) for minimal example.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not mocking the component method itself, but rather creating a new mock function and assign it to a random variable.

Try to mock the method through the object prototype before rendering as follows:

```
jest.mock('../Form'); // mock the component before importing it using the right path
import Form from '../Form';
...
it('should submit form data', () => {
  Form.prototype.handleSubmit = jest.fn();
  let form = shallow(<Form />);

  form.find('.submit-btn').simulate('submit');

  expect(form.find('.submit-btn').length).toEqual(1);
  expect(Form.prototype.handleSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

**Note**: not sure which jest version are you using but since Jest v15, automocking is disabled by default, so you need to explicitly mock your module before importing it in the file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I'm still getting the same `Expected mock function to have been called.` error. Please, can you explain why when I use `shallow` or `mount` on an imported component, `jest.fn()` is not called? Because I'm following all the steps from tutorials and your answer, but still not working. But if I `mount` my own fake component in the test itself, then it works.

Comment: Check my question, I've updated it with the fake component I created inside my test. And it works. But not with the imported one.

Comment: Could you try to mock the method through the prototype instead? I edited the first 2 lines on my code snippet. Don't forget to mock your module before importing it. Also, as I see you do in your fake component, better to simulate a 'submit' event rather than a 'click'.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input className="card-submit-btn btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save" />
```

Your component isn't using className `.submit-btn`, it's using `.card-submit-btn`.